# Routing a exe File to have a backup target when servers fail

Tags: mysql, batch-file, cmd, server, exe

I was wondering what solution is there to give a shortcut to a server, basically an exe, More that 1 target path to basically have the same application on 2 servers so that when one server fails, that the exe goes to the other target path and find the exact same application exe that the shortcut points to. Any solutions would be highly appreciated. Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer gave me a guideline to what worked in my situation and i came up with a c# application ran from the local C: drive:

```
        string Directory1 = @"\\sqlsvr01\Releases\Filename";
        string Directory2 = @"\\sqlsvr02\Releases\filename";

        string server1 = @"\\sqlsvr01\Releases\Filename\setup.exe";
        string server2 = @"\\sqlsvr02\Releases\Filename\setup.exe";


        //look for the file on sqlsvr01 - main publish folder
        if (Directory.Exists(Directory1))
        {
            Process.Start(server1);
            Console.WriteLine("SQLSVR01 reached");
            Console.WriteLine("Executing setup.exe from SQLSVR01");
            Console.ReadLine();

            


        }//if the folders are not found in sqlsvr01 - look for the file on 
          //sqlsvr02 - secondary publish folder
        else if (Directory.Exists(Directory2))
        {
            Process.Start(server2);
            Console.WriteLine("sqlsvr02 reached");
            Console.WriteLine("Executing setup.exe from sqlsvr02");
            Console.ReadLine();

           
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("None accessible");
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Test if file exist (is reachable) on prefered server. If yes, start it. If no, start it from backup server. You have to adapt script paths to UNC path or mapped drives, depend on what you are using. UNTESTED:

```
set "_path=path_to_exe"
set server1=hostname1
set server2=hostname2

if exist "%server1%\%_path%\file.exe" (
   "%server1%\%_path%\file.exe"
   ) else (
   "%server2%\%_path%\file.exe"
   )
```

Comment: `%PATH%` is a special variable. It is not advisable to try to use this for another purpose. [Path on SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/path.html)

Comment: You are right, variable name just changed to _path. Thanks for notification

Answer (score 0):

It`s impossible to achieve such only by a shortcut.
You can find some opensource HA(high available) or clustering solutions.